# NA of pred values in a trained model in R (Caret)

Tags: r

```
set.seed(2)
rpcv <- trainControl(method='repeatedcv', number=4, repeats = 10,
                     savePredictions = T, classProbs = T)

iris2 <- iris[c(1:3,60:72,100:109),]

iris2_train <- iris2[-1,]
iris2_test <- iris2[1,]

set.seed(4)
iris_svm <- train(as.factor(Species)~., data=iris2_train, method='svmRadial', trControl=rpcv)

iris_svm$pred
```

If you look at iris$pred, you can see that there is an NA value. What's the problem?

Comment: Please specify all non-base packages you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I think your train data set have small number of sample  class setosa (just 2 samples) which too small , so run models with a large enough n and class balance

so try this

```
library(caret)

set.seed(2)
rpcv <- trainControl(method='repeatedcv', number=4, repeats = 10,
                     savePredictions = T, classProbs = T)

# here i increased the sample of class setosa
iris2 <- iris[c(1:10,60:72,100:109),]

iris2_train <- iris2[-1,]
iris2_test <- iris2[1,]

set.seed(4)
iris_svm <- train(as.factor(Species)~., data=iris2_train, method='svmRadial', trControl=rpcv)

iris_svm$pred
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, if it is a sample problem, it should not be run in other algorithms. For example, in the case of a random forest(`method = rf`), it shows all values. What is the reason for this? @Mohamed

Comment: It depends on the algorithm, whoever it is good ml practice is to feed the algorithm with sufficient size of samples and balance the classes